# get ip address of local machine using javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket

When I use `Request.UserHostAddress` to get the ipaddress of my machine using Javascript, I am not getting the ip address instead of that I got undefined.

My code:

```
var ip = Request.UserHostAddress;
console.log(ip);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try below code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 Ip Address:=<h3 class='ipAdd'><h3>
  </body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function ubsrt()
{
   window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;  
 var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers:[]}), 
 noop = function(){}; 
     
    pc.createDataChannel("");  
 pc.createOffer(pc.setLocalDescription.bind(pc), noop);   
     pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){ 
    if(!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate)  return;

         var myIP = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/.exec(ice.candidate.candidate)[1];

         console.log('my IP: ', myIP); 
 $('.ipAdd').text(myIP);
  
         pc.onicecandidate = noop;
  
  }; 
});
      
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do an ajax call to hostip.info or a similar service...

```
function myIP() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        else xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php",false);
        xmlhttp.send();

        hostipInfo = xmlhttp.responseText.split("\n");

        for (i=0; hostipInfo.length >= i; i++) {
            ipAddress = hostipInfo[i].split(":");
            if ( ipAddress[0] == "IP" ) return ipAddress[1];
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my verson of the answer. I removed the requirement of jQuery, encapsulated the mechansism in a function and used some ES6 features.

```
<html>
<head><title>My IP Address</title></head>
<body><h3 class='ipAdd'>Ip Address : <h3></body>

<script> "use strict";
  window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection ||
                             window.mozRTCPeerConnection ||
                             window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;  

  function getMyIP (cb) {
    // Calls the cb function with the local host IP address found 
    // using RTC functions. We cannot just return the IP address 
    // because the RTC functions are asynchronous.

    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection ({iceServers: []}),
        noop = () => {};

    pc.onicecandidate = ice => 
      cb = cb ((ice = ice && ice.candidate && ice.candidate.candidate)
                   ? ice.match (/(\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}|[a-f\d]{1,4}(:[a-f\d]{1,4}){7})/)[1]
                   : 'unavailable') || noop;
    pc.createDataChannel ("");  
    pc.createOffer (pc.setLocalDescription.bind (pc), noop);
  };

  getMyIP (addr => { document.querySelector ('.ipAdd').innerHTML += addr; });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Can you tell me how does it work without jquery?

Comment: The original version used only two calls to jQuery. The first `$(document).ready` is not necessary and the second `$('.ipAdd').text(myIP)`  I replaced with the DOM version : `document.querySelector ('.ipAdd').innerHTML += addr;`

Comment: Understood your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 Ip Address:=<h3 class='ipAdd'><h3>
  </body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function ubsrt()
{
   window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;  
 var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers:[]}), 
 noop = function(){}; 
     
    pc.createDataChannel("");  
 pc.createOffer(pc.setLocalDescription.bind(pc), noop);   
     pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){ 
    if(!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate)  return;

         var myIP = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/.exec(ice.candidate.candidate)[1];

         console.log('my IP: ', myIP); 
 $('.ipAdd').text(myIP);
  
         pc.onicecandidate = noop;
  
  }; 
});
      
</script>
</html>
```